# How to use a fonticon inside a NativeScript <Button>

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm running into a font-family collision when trying to use a icon font on a `<Button>`.

For example:

```
<Button class="btn btn-primary fas" text="{{'fa-film' | fonticon}} Test"></Button>
```

CSS:

```
.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free Solid', fa-solid-900;
}
```

When using the Nativescript themes, it [defines](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/blob/c7bf1010505577031a3bcf3e4ff864c1ab1bbcd0/app/scss/platforms/_buttons.ios.scss) the `font-family` for the `.btn` class. As you know iconfonts rely on `font-family` as well.

So in the button above how do apply one `font-family` to the string Test while applying another `font-family` to the icon?

If you use the NativeScript [Angular SASS starter app](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-sass/tree/master/demo-angular/app) and define .fas in `_app-common.scss` and use my button above, you will see that the icon displays as a ?. This is because `.btn` is overriding the `font-family`.

I could solve this by giving the icon `font-family` a higher precedence - but this would prevent me from styling the textual font on the button.

Non-nativescript implementations of font icons inside buttons solve it by being able to put an element (like `<span>`) as a child element to `<Button>`. Example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons-examples).

How can you accomplish this with NativeScript `<Button>`?

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, man I had ton of mistakes - too early ;)

Answer (score 16):

The answer is to use [FormattedString](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/formatted-string).  It allows you to apply a `class` to each element.

Ex:

```
<Button (tap)="onTap($event)" class="btn btn-primary">
    <FormattedString>
        <Span class="fas" text="{{'fa-film' | fonticon}}"></Span>
        <Span text=" Test" fontAttributes="Bold"></Span>            
    </FormattedString>
</Button>
```

Comment: what is `fonticon` ?